# Google Ecommerce tracking code not working

Tags: google-analytics

My client has asked me to implement GA ecommerce code in their ecommerce website. So I added the code to the success page. I just purchased an item from the site, and the following is the code that was generated. I have already checked the settings of the site in GA and the site is set as a Ecommerce site. Can anybody see anything wrong with this code and explain why its not working?!

Regards,
Fiona

var gaJsHost = (("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https://ssl." : "http://www."); document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='" + gaJsHost + "google-analytics.com/ga.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));  try { var pageTracker = _gat._getTracker("UA-XXXXXXXX-5"); pageTracker._trackPageview(); pageTracker._addTrans( "502085","","35.5","0","5.5","Test","Tyne","United Kingdom" ); pageTracker_addItem("502085","229","INA Crystals Restoring Night Serum","FeaturedHome","30","1");pageTracker._trackTrans();} catch(err){}

Comment: When you say just bought an item, do you mean within the last 24 hours? GAs data isn't live so it might take some time to come through.

Comment: Thanks for answering me. The code was implemented last Friday and there have been hundreds of transactions since. None were reported on. I just put through that transaction to get a copy of the source code being generated.

Comment: Also thought I should mention that this ecommerce site is a Dot Net Storefront shopping cart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem:

pageTracker_addItem

missing a '.'!!

Should be

pageTracker._addItem

Thanks,
Fiona